# Почему у меня ошибка "must be real number, not str"?

Tags: python

```
import math
def main_1():
    """Дана сторона равностороннего треугольника. Найти площадь этого треугольника"""
    a=input('Сторона равностроннего треугольника = ')
    S=(math.pow(a,2)*math.sqrt(3))/4
    print('Площадь треугольника S =',S)
    return S
```

Comment: потому что у вас а-строка, а не число. почитайте Типы данных в Python

Comment: `a = float(input(...))`